# Issue with Scope and Access

Tags: java

Using Java and trying to solve the following problem, my code keeps giving this error:

"TesterClass.java:41: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
return numerator;"

The code is supposed to print out 0 and and a 1.

I have changed about everything around, I know it is a scope and access issue, just not sure where it is.

```
public class TesterClass
{

public static void main(String[] args)
     {
Fraction f1 = new Fraction();
Fraction f2 = new Fraction(1,2);
System.out.println(f1);
System.out.println(f2.numerator / f2.denominator);  //class Scope
    }
}

/** Class Fraction */
class Fraction
{
// instance variables
private int numerator;
private int denominator;

// constructor: set instance variables to default values
public Fraction()
    {
int d = 1;
numerator = d;
denominator = d;
    }

// constructor
public Fraction(int initNumerator, int initDenominator)
    {
numerator = initNumerator;
denominator = initDenominator;
    }
 
public String toString()
    {
if (denominator == 1)
return numerator;
return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }

public int getNum()
   {
return numerator;
   }

public int getDen()
   {
return denominator;
   }
}
```

Should print out

1
0

Answer (score 1):

`return numerator;` in itself cannot work because the method is supposed to return a `String` but `numerator`is of type `int`.

If you want to keep the distiction using `if (denominator == 1)` you need to manually convert numerator to a `String`.
You could for example do that using

```py
return String.valueOf(numerator)
```

(thanks @Antonio)

Comment: When I remove that line, I get the following error now:  TesterClass.java:43: error: missing return statement
}

Comment: @Mr. Rhodes I think you need to convert `numerator` from `int` to `String` with `String.valueOf(numerator)`.

Answer (score 0):

You also trying access private fields numerator and denominator from TesterClass class.

To solve your error you may do:

```
public String toString() {
    if (denominator == 1)
        return numerator+"";
    return numerator + "/" + denominator;
}
```

Comment: I think this was the answer I was looking for from the start.  I need the + " " to keep it a string.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TesterClass
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Fraction f1 = new Fraction();
    Fraction f2 = new Fraction(1,2);
    System.out.println(f1.getNum());
    System.out.println(f1);
    System.out.println(f2);
    }
}

/** Class Fraction */
class Fraction
{
    // instance variables
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
    
    // constructor: set instance variables to default values
    public Fraction()
    {
    int d = 1;
    int n = 1;
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
    }
// constructor: set instance variables to init parameters 

public Fraction(int initNumerator, int initDenominator)
    {
    numerator = initNumerator;
    denominator = initDenominator;
    }

public String toString()
    {
    if (denominator == 1)
    return String.valueOf(numerator);
    return String.valueOf(numerator) + "/" + String.valueOf(denominator);
    }

public int getNum()
    {
    return numerator;
    }
    
public int getDen()
    {
    return denominator;
    }
}
```